# Disconnecting From SUP

Tags: ios, sup

My project supports two type of Connection viz SUP & Web Service. If user selects Web Service, connection to SUP should be disconnected. I use [SUPMessageClient stop] to disconnect. This functions stops the SUP, but when I try to connect to SUP again using [SUPMessageClient start] or [SUPMessageClient restart]  none of the methods of call back handler gets called. Is this right way to disconnect from SUP? If not then what is right way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are u changing the network??? 
If Yes then you must know that changing the network in between the running application is not possible.
If NO then you can create a MBO of web service and can use in your project